# Expanding the size of an array of strings in c

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I am trying to get strings from the user and then expand the size of the strings if they enter a long string and also expand the size of the array holding the strings if they enter more strings than expected.Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int number_of_strings = 5;
    int string_size = 5;
    int count = 0;
    char **array = (char**)calloc(number_of_strings, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_strings; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (char*)calloc(string_size + 1, sizeof(char));
    }

////////////////////////////MAIN PART///////////////////////////////////////////////
    int arr_size = number_of_strings;
    int str_count = 0;                          //Total number of input strings counter

    for (int j = 0; j < arr_size; j++)
    {
        if (arr_size >= str_count)              //Check if the number of input strings is more than expected
        {
            array = (char**)realloc(array, (arr_size + 1) * sizeof(char*));     //allocate memory for 1 more string
            arr_size++;                         //Increase the loop rounds
        }

        int str_size = string_size; 
        int char_count = 0;                     //Total number of input characters counter

        for (int h = 0; h < str_size; h++)
        {
            if (str_size >= char_count)         //Check if the input string size is more than expected
            {
                array[j] = (char*)realloc(array[j], (str_size + 1) * sizeof(char));     //allocate memory for 1 more char
                str_size++;                     //Increase the loop rounds
            }
            scanf(" %c", &array[j][h]);         //get a single char
            char_count++;                       //Increment the total input character count
        }
        str_count++;                            //Increment the total input string count
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    for (int k = 0; k < number_of_strings; k++)
    {
        printf("%s", array[k]);
        free(array[k]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:**Thisisnot whatitlooks likebut Idon't knowwhy isthis happening**
Output: **Empty Stdout . Time limit exceeded**
Expected Output: **ThisisnotwhatitlookslikebutIdon'tknowwhyisthishappening**

The program waits for user input for a long time and it doesn't stop scanning for inputs, even if the user doesn't enter any input and so eventually the program crashes.

I think the error is caused due to improper reallocation of the array. Any idea about why is this error caused and how can it be fixed is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Reduce it to a [mcve] of *just the part that's a problem*.  We're not here to debug a full program like that.  And don't cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do. Here are some problems in the code:

- you purposely ignore whitespace from the input, so how can you detect string boundaries?
- all of the input is clumped into a single string the inner loop never stops.
- you do not check for EOF either: if the end of the input stream is encountered, the loop continues, reallocating memory until a system crash or an allocation failure...
- allocation failure is not tested either, so undefined behavior in all cases.
- there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` and `calloc` in C. It is necessary in C++, but you would definitely want to use a different approach in C++. To avoid type discrepancies, you can use the type of the destination pointer instead of hard coding it: to reallocate the array, replace `array = (char**)realloc(array, (arr_size + 1) * sizeof(char*));` with

  ```
  array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * (arr_size + 1));
  ```

Comment: ...and don't cast the result of calloc and realloc.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: good point, but relatively minor compared to the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks your suggestions fixed the problem.